# How to handle service roads off of highways?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, road, transportation

I am setting up a road network for a our rural municipality in Canada, and I am wondering how to handle the service roads that run parallel to our highways. The buildings along these service roads have addressing based on the highway, so it wouldn't make sense to create names for these roads.

I am wondering what other people do in situations like this, and if there is a "best practices" way to handle this. None of them have official names, so would naming the roads (simply for presentation purposes) something like "HWY 52 Service Road" be a good idea, or simply leave them unnamed, but still have them drawn out so that they appear in maps.

Comment: Here those roads are called Frontage Roads. So the road that runs along side I-35 is simply I-35 NB Frontage  for the northbound, SB for the southbound.  I am not sure if that is a universal naming method or not.

Comment: That is what I was thinking of doing, thanks for your reply!

Comment: {Sorry, this should be a comment, but I'm not allowed to comment} moderator moved to comments >. If your road network needs to function as a network, i.e., routing and cartographic representations, the service roads will need to be built into the road network just like all the other roads. (Maybe I am reading too much into your question.)

Comment: classification of the road would be better than renaming roads 'service road' is generic

Comment: They will be tied into the road network, but I am thinking I'll set them up without any addressing, so that the buildings get the address directly from the highway. The name will look something like "Hwy 52 Service Rd." so that people will have an idea that it's a service road directly off of a major highway. Does this make sense?

Comment: Also, I will give the roads proper classification when I migrate into a proper data model.

Comment: That makes sense to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this an answer for others:

Here those roads are called Frontage Roads. So the road that runs along side I-35 is simply I-35 NB Frontage for the northbound, SB for the southbound. I am not sure if that is a universal naming method or not. Since you are using a road network you will need to give the roads proper classification and possibly define things like one-way etc... And yes using the HWY to generate addressing is what we do here as well, as even though the business is on a frontage road of that highway it is still really on that highway, you just need to exit off the hwy to the frontage road to get to it.